# flutter widget: flutter_map don't work, missing latLng function

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, widget

I want o test this (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) widget map from Flutter.
but i can found what to import to solve dependency to this method: **LatLng**.

This method is used to set a point on many places on the first example.
Can someone tell me what lib to import to solve this dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:

Install [latlong2](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong2) package simply by doing `flutter pub add latlong2`

---

**Long answer:**

On the right side of pub.dev you can find a dependency list, in this case it's this:

[image]

You should already be able to do `import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';` but probably the linter will notify you not to use dependencies that are not defined in your `pubspec.yaml`, so you have to explicitly add `latlong2: ^x.x.x` to your pubspec.